# Is someone have idea to recover file from Dreamweaver cs6 in windows?

Tags: windows, backup, dreamweaver

I have worked from 2-3 days and now I find css file got corrupted. Now I am frustrated because I have not made any backup. I have made a upload to testing server when I have started a little bit.

Can someone let me know how you like to make backup of code.

Comment: Is this happen because I am using trial

Comment: no. Trial software is not the reason.

Comment: Is it just your local file that has got corrupt or did it get corrupted when you uploaded it?

Comment: Actually my power-backup has failed and I am waiting for next day to go for repair. My light is going and when I open file is goes corrupted. it's bad luck for me that I got loose all thing I made.

Answer (score 0):

Version control is the best option for software Maintenance. I personally prefer GIT.
http://git-scm.com/

Comment: How I can use version control. Do you know any software that make me able to create lot's of copy on my computer or sync them online when I made changes.

Comment: creating multiple copies r not the right approach. Because if u edit 1 copy u have to edit all ur copies. so only v use version control.